# SLARToolkit Detect an image in a poster

Tags: windows-phone-7, augmented-reality, object-detection

I am using SLARToolkit for Windows Phone and I am aware of how the toolkit uses markers to identify objects via the camera.

However, I would like the toolkit to recognize a certain image from the poster, e.g.:

[image]
<sub>(source: [burgerbusiness.com](http://www.burgerbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/BurgerBar_LV_keller.jpg))</sub>

In this poster I would like to detect the burger on the top right of that poster. How can I do that? Also, is there a better alternative for AR in WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a duplicate of the question posted at the project site and answered by me: http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/394101

> You can create custom markers, but they need to be b/w and framed by a black square. Here's how to: http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation